# Regular expression non ending word linux terminal

Tags: regex, linux, grep, find, cpu-word

I have this code

```
grep -P "(?<=|^)some [a-z]+s\b" file.txt
```

And it matches all the words that end with an -s but if I write this

```
grep -P "(?<=|^)some [a-z]+[^s]\b" file.txt
```

If I have:

```
some girls

some girl

some guys

some guy

some apples

some apple
```

I want to find "some girl", "some apple" and "some guy"

Comment: you have a clerical error in your regex: `(?<=|^)some [a-z]+[^s]\b` (note the closing bracket instead of a closing brace in your class of lowercase characters).

Comment: Provide more examples with some sample data

Comment: Writing `(?<=|^)` is useless since it's an always-true assertion. You can remove it. Note that `[^s]` matches all characters except `s` but not all letters except `s`.

Comment: How are those "errors"? As in, "Could you please give me some apple seeds?" or "That bully was picking on some girl at lunch time."...

Comment: `some [a-z]+` matches `some girl` and `some boys`. The `[^s]` won't help

Comment: Given your update, the much simpler `grep -v 's$' file.txt` would be sufficient

Answer (score 1):

I think you only want the lines with a girl in it with the next file:

```
something wrong
some girl I know
some girl knows some boys 
some boys know nothing
```

The last letter shouldn't be a s:

```
grep -P 'some [a-z]+[a-rt-z]\b'
```